# oracle query for number of partition in a table

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

How can I add a number of partition for each table in this given oracle query?

```
SELECT
    ab.table_name,
    ab.table_owner AS schema_name,
    ab.partition_name,
    ab.num_rows,
    ab.last_analyzed,
    ab.partition_position,
    apk.column_name as partition_column,
    apk.column_position,
    1 as is_partition_column
FROM
    all_tab_partitions ab
    JOIN ALL_PART_KEY_COLUMNS apk ON apk.owner = ab.table_owner
    AND apk.name = table_name
WHERE
    partition_position != 1
```

Comment: Is there a reason this is tagged for MySQL?  Are you trying to run the same query against both Oracle and MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.  Note that you have to provide some sort order on the inner query, otherwise row number really has no meaning. I just chose ab.table_name for an example

```
select * from 
(
SELECT
    ab.table_name,
    ab.table_owner AS schema_name,
    ab.partition_name,
    ab.num_rows,
    ab.last_analyzed,
    ab.partition_position,
    apk.column_name as partition_column,
    apk.column_position,
    rownum rnum
FROM
    all_tab_partitions ab
    JOIN ALL_PART_KEY_COLUMNS apk ON apk.owner = ab.table_owner
    AND apk.name = table_name
    order by ab.table_name
)
where rnum <> 1
order by rnum
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a *number of partition for each table* is as trivial as adding the following subquery ...

i.e.

```
select
   (select count(*) from all_tab_partitions  where table_name = ab.table_name and table_owner = ab.table_owner) as partition_count,
   ab.table_name,
   ab.table_owner AS schema_name,
   -- rest of the query
```

... but you should consider some potential problems

1. you query does **not show all partitioned tables**, you ignore tables with only one partition.
2. you query output one row per *partition* (ignoring the first one) and *partition key* - so the good question is why do you need to add partition count to each row.

*Example* a table with 5 partitions and 2 partition keys - you get 4 * 2 rows in each row the partition count = 5.